# how to check syslog for ubuntu docker

Tags: ubuntu, logging, docker, syslog

I installed [`tutum/ubuntu`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/ubuntu/) in local vm's docker.

When I login to `ubuntu` and run below command.

```
logger "Test Logging"
```

I can't find the file where this logged in. In my local system I can see the `system.log` or `syslog` or `messages` file in `/var/log`. But when I check `/var/log` in container, I can't find any file like this.

```
root@fbc4ae457ad9:~# ls -al /var/log/
total 316
drwxrwxr-x  6 root syslog   4096 Jun 20 16:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root     4096 Jun 20 16:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     9174 Mar 17 15:17 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Mar 17 15:17 apt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    47816 Mar 15 04:34 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw----  1 root utmp      768 Jun 20 16:49 btmp
-rw-r-----  1 root adm        31 Mar 15 04:34 dmesg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   213169 Mar 17 15:17 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     3296 Mar 17 15:17 faillog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Mar 15 04:34 fsck
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp    30076 Jun 20 16:53 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 11  2014 upstart
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp     1920 Jun 20 16:53 wtmp
```

I check in `upstart` and other directory, but all are empty.

Which file I have to check for `systemlog` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no rsyslogd installed by default, nor in this image you are using.

If you wish to utilize rsyslogd in your docker container, you should install/configure it by your self via Dockerfile first.

```
RUN apt-get -y install rsyslog
```

You will probably need supervisord as well to have all your processes started in container.

Comment: @Nilesh there is a bunch of them at docker hub, try some:  https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=rsyslog&starCount=0